# Check Lists to be considered before migrating data from SQL Server to SharePoint

Tags: sql-server, migration, console-application, sharepoint-2013

We have a requirement to migrate only data from SQL Server to SharePoint 2013.I wish to analyze the SQL server database details prior proceeding to migrate to SharePoint.So, can anyone guide me on what factors or what kind of information I need to gather from SQL serer to take those into consideration prior deciding to migrate to SP?

Please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Please guide me on this."* isn't a question. Also, Sharepoint uses SQL Server as a data backend; why are you trying to migrate data out of SQL Server, that is going to then be stored back in it? Seems like an XY problem here.

Comment: Hello Larnu,

Client has a custom data base used for some application other than SharePoint.
Now, they want if feasible migrate those data inside the DB into share point.

That is why I need to analyze their custom data base first and need to check whether it is feasible to move the data into share point or not.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clear about what you meant by SQL server to SharePoint migration :-) - by the design, SharePoint maintains its back end data in SQL server - and the database name called as content database. So are you trying to migrate these content databases to some other SharePoint version or farm? If you are looking for this, please go thru the below article for basic tips and tricks in SharePoint migration project.

https://global-sharepoint.com/2019/10/13/basic-tips-and-tricks-in-sharepoint-migration-project/

Comment: Hello Habibur,

Client has a custom data base used for some application other than SharePoint.
Now, they want if feasible migrate those data inside the DB into share point.

That is why I need to analyze their custom data base first and need to check whether it is feasible to move the data into share point or not.

Comment: @KailashSahoo: Before discussing this, then we need to understand those custom databases for what type of application I mean they run on which technology. Directly we cannot migrate non content database to content database of SharePoint as content database has different schema. So in this case we need to look for any third party tool which support non SharePoint application migration to SharePoint, but we should think in the application level migration not directly database migration. Hope you will get  third party tool to do this.

Comment: @KailashSahoo, I remember a third party tool which will migrate from non Microsoft application to SharePoint i.e. FME Migration center.https://www.migration-center.com/